# Recover deleted firebase storage rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I made a newbie mistake and accidentally deleted my storage rules.  Is there any way to recover these?
The firestore rules keep previous versions but it seems not the storage.

How I deleted them:
I had been developing the rules direct in the firebase console and then I accidentally did a full deploy from VScode.  The local versions of the storage rules were just the initial default ones which were deployed and overwrote my most recent ones.

I won't be doing this again, I will develop locally from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you lose your rules in the console, there is currently no way of getting them back like you can with Firestore.  You could also try [contacting Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) for assistance.